# How do I add an Alert box and have it display when a Google Site Loads

Tags: google-sites

As per the title, I'd like to have an alert box display when a Google Sites page loads.

I've tried using the HTML Box and inline HTML but haven't had any luck as yet.

I have been able to generate the alert box via a link, but to display it when the page loads is where I'm struggling.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert("My alert box content here");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've tried this code, but when I add it to a HTML Box I'm not getting any alert and it can't be added inline. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you **positive** that Google Sites allows JavaScript?

Comment: As far as I know, google sites (the new version, anyway) sandboxes the HTML and is trying to move away from the ability to embed. They sandbox it in an iframe, which has the option to disable the allowance of window.alerts along with a lot of other things. Therefore, I think they might have disabled that option.